# bash: will the read command recive input from an empty command?

Tags: bash, input, command

new to bash. i want a "while read line" loop the gets input from a command-in this case, grep. i want the read to read each line the grep returns and insert it as a string to the "line" var. in case the grep returns no results, i still want it to enter the loop so i can printf something and then continue. will it work? here's the code segement:

```
while read -r line: do

    ...(irrelevent)...

        done<$(grep $id ${arrpre[$j]}.course)
```

${arrpre[$j]}.course is the name of the file. tnx for the help!

Comment: Do you want to read *from the output of `grep`*, or from *a file named as the output of grep*? This code is doing the latter.

Comment: ...if you want the loop to iterate over the output itself, that would be either `done < <(grep ...)` or `done <<<"$(grep ...)"`

Comment: ... Or `grep ... | while ...`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, ...though that's subject to the pitfalls described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: That's true, @CharlesDuffy, and in that respect, the loop body indeed is *not* irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [I]n case the grep returns no results, i still want it to enter the loop so i can printf something and then continue. will it work?

No.  If you're piping the output of a command (i.e. `grep`) into the `while` loop, and that command produces no output at all, then `read` will see end-of-file on its first execution.  `read` returns a failure code when it encounters end-of-file, which will cause the loop to terminate without its body being executed.  If this were not the case then you would have an extra iteration of the `while` loop in every case, whether there was any data to read or not.

But you can explicitly record whether the loop body is ever executed, and afterward take appropriate action.  For example:

```
empty=1
while read -r line: do
  empty=0
  #  ...
done < $(grep $id ${arrpre[$j]}.course)

if [ $empty -eq 1 ]; then
  # ... stuff to do in the event of empty grep output
fi
```

Comment: `< $(grep ...)`, not `< <(grep ...)` or `<<<"$(grep ...)"`? I think you're propagating an error the OP made here.

Comment: great help! tnx alot

Comment: I just copied the OP's code, @CharlesDuffy.  It is probably incorrect, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, ...not *necessarily*, but I'm sure enough it's incorrect to bet my pocket change on it. :)

Comment: If you really want to execute the same code (the stuff in the loop), rather than repeating it as a separate `if` block, use `while read -r line || [ "$empty" -eq 1 ]; do`.